# Yii2 Active Record вложенность моделей

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Есть страница задания, на которой отображаются категория задания и отклики исполнителей по этому заданию. У одного задания может быть только одна категория - связь `hasOne`, но откликов может быть несколько.
Проблема в чем, по коду `$model->category->name` я получаю имя категории, потому что категория это экземпляр класса `model`. При этом тоже самое относительно отклика не работает `$reply->performer_id->name (Attempt to read property "name" on int)`.

```
object(app\models\Task)#93 (13) { ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=> string(7) "default" ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(13) { ["id"]=> int(23) ["publication_dt"]=> string(19) "2023-07-28 10:02:56" ["title"]=> string(10) "Voluptate." ["description"]=> string(29) "Minus aut corporis assumenda." ["budget"]=> int(14301) ["files"]=> NULL ["status_id"]=> int(1) ["execution_dt"]=> NULL ["category_id"]=> int(4) ["client_id"]=> int(5) ["performer_id"]=> int(1) ["city_id"]=> int(243) ["adress"]=> NULL } ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(13) { ["id"]=> int(23) ["publication_dt"]=> string(19) "2023-07-28 10:02:56" ["title"]=> string(10) "Voluptate." ["description"]=> string(29) "Minus aut corporis assumenda." ["budget"]=> int(14301) ["files"]=> NULL ["status_id"]=> int(1) ["execution_dt"]=> NULL ["category_id"]=> int(4) ["client_id"]=> int(5) ["performer_id"]=> int(1) ["city_id"]=> int(243) ["adress"]=> NULL } ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(2) { ["city"]=> object(app\models\City)#122 (10) { ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=> string(7) "default" ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(243) ["name"]=> string(14) "Джанкой" ["latitude"]=> string(10) "45.7092436" ["longditude"]=> string(10) "34.3883320" } ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(243) ["name"]=> string(14) "Джанкой" ["latitude"]=> string(10) "45.7092436" ["longditude"]=> string(10) "34.3883320" } ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } } ["category"]=> object(app\models\Category)#131 (10) { ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=> string(7) "default" ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["character_code"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(37) "Компьютерная помощь" ["icon"]=> string(3) "neo" } ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["character_code"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(37) "Компьютерная помощь" ["icon"]=> string(3) "neo" } ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } } }
```

Модель в контроллере

```
    public function getPerformer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, ['id' => 'performer_id']);
}

/**
 * Gets query for [[Ratings]].
 *
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|RatingQuery
 */
public function getRatings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Rating::class, ['task_id' => 'id']);
}
```

связи в моделе Task

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Весь код, что изображен на картинках не влезет в карточку вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> При этом тоже самое относительно отклика не работает

Нет, не тоже самое. Потому что вы пишите `performer_id`, вместо того, чтобы писать имя связи.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Теперь все работает!